# plot multiple images from classification categories

Tags: python, deep-learning

Hello I'm doing a multiple classification of images and I want to plot 3 images from each category
here is the code

```
i=0
labels=[]

for label in y_train:
    if not label in labels :
        labels.append(label)
        print("Category  : ", y_train[i])
        plt.imshow(plt.imread(train_dir+"/"+train_files[i]))
        plt.show()
    i+=1
    if len(labels)==11:
       break 
print('[INFO] done')
```

this code plots only one image from every category, how can i modify it to plot 3 images from the 11 categories.
I'm new to all this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use a dict instead of a list:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
i=0
labels={}
y_train = ['a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c']
for label in y_train:
    if not label in labels :
        labels[label] = 0
    else:
        labels[label] += 1
    if labels[label] <3:
        print("Category  : ", y_train[i])
        #plt.imshow(plt.imread(train_dir+"/"+train_files[i]))
        plt.plot(1,1,'ko')
        plt.text(1,1,f'{label} --> plot {labels[label]}')
        plt.show()
    i+=1
    if len(labels)==11:
       break 
print('[INFO] done')
```

According to your comment. If you want them in one plot and they do not appear sorted and you do not know in advance how many labels and plots you have you need a two step process like this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
i=0
mydict={}
y_train = ['a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c']
for label in y_train:
    if not label in mydict :
        mydict[label] = {}
    if len (mydict[label]) < 3:
        print(f"Storing data for {label} image {len(mydict[label])}")
        image_No = len(mydict[label])
        mydict[label][image_No] = {}
        mydict[label][image_No]["xdata"] = 1
        mydict[label][image_No]["ydata"] = 1


for label in mydict:
    plt.figure()
    for im in mydict[label]:
        plt.subplot(1,3,im+1)
        plt.plot(mydict[label][im]["xdata"],mydict[label][im]["xdata"],'ko')
        plt.text(mydict[label][im]["xdata"],mydict[label][im]["xdata"],label)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: It kinda works, but I need it to show the 3 images from the same categories in the same row, I don't know if it's clear